# How do I specify application version in dot42 project?

Tags: android, dot42

How do I specify apk version for dot42 project? I look into my project obj folder, and AndroidManifest.xml has `android:versionName="0.0.0.0"`. How do I change that?

**UPDATE**: Found it.

```
[assembly: Package(VersionName = "1.0.0")]
```